# PDA for parentheses language

Tags: automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

> Construct a PDA for the language described by the following CFG:
>   $$ S \to [S] \mid \{S\} \mid \Lambda $$

How can I develop a pushdown automaton for this language?

Comment: In addition to showing how far you got on your own: what would be a *simpler* language accepted by a PDA, but not a finite one? (Oh, wait, there used to be curly braces)

Answer (score 0):

When you see [ or {, push it onto the stack.

When you see ], pop [ off the stack (if [ is not the top of stack, reject).

When you see }, pop { off the stack (if { is not the top of stack, reject).

Accept if at end of input, the stack is empty.

Comment: What about that symbol which is present there what does that stand for???

Comment: I have no idea what you're referring to. Note that your question would have been the same even with a single question mark.

Comment: That inverted V symbol which is seen in the production have any idea about that???

Comment: It stands for the empty string. It feels like you should find better study materials. The empty string is a basic concept that would have been covered in class. We cannot stand for your course materials.

Comment: You cannot expect to answer questions such as constructing a PDF for a grammar, if you don't understand the syntax of grammars.

Comment: We were thought with ( e ) epsilon

Comment: There are several common notations. I also use $\epsilon$. Where is this question taken from, then?

Comment: It is taken from our university question paper

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt ☺️